# Puppeteer not work correctly with handlebars and get only blank page PDF

Tags: node.js, pdf, handlebars.js, puppeteer

Hello im working in application that i want to create PDF files using puppeteer and handlbars but it create only blank PDF

Here is my code
File : functions.js

```
    createPDF = async (templateName, data, file_name) => {


  const pdfPath = `${process.cwd()}/public/tickets/${file_name}.pdf`;
  const filePath = path.join(process.cwd(), "templates", `${templateName}.hbs`);
  const html = fs.readFileSync(filePath, "utf-8");
  const content = hbs.compile(html);
  const htmlContent = content(data);

  const options = {
    format: "A4",
    headerTemplate: "<p></p>",
    footerTemplate: "<p></p>",
    displayHeaderFooter: false,
    margin: {
      top: "10px",
      bottom: "30px",
    },
    printBackground: true,
    path: pdfPath,
  };

  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    args: ["--no-sandbox"],
    headless: true,
  });

  const page = await browser.newPage();

  await page.goto(`data:text/html;charset=UTF-8,${htmlContent}`, {
    waitUntil: "networkidle0",
  });

  console.log(await page.content());

  await page.pdf(options);
  await browser.close();

};
```

fileContoller.js

```
    exports.myfile = async (req, res, next) => {
  const { approved } = req.body;
  const getData = await MyTable.findAll({
    attributes: [
"id",
      "first_name",
      "last_name",
      "birthday",
      "gender",
      "address",
       "img",
    ],
    where: { approved},
    raw: true,
  });

  for (let i = 0; i < getData.length; i++) {

    const createPDFforuser = await functions.createPDF(
      "myhbsmockuptemplate",
      getData[i],
      `${getData[i].id}+${i}`
    );
  }

}
```

when i console.log htmlContent it get the html complete and correctly done as i write it

But when i console log awit page.content()
Here i dont get the html as expected it get only few line

```
<html><head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style type="text/css">
  .tmp-mockup { font-family: "Staatliches", cursive; color: black;
  font-size: 14px; letter-spacing: 0.1em; margin: 25px 0; } .ticket-box {
  margin: auto; display: flex; background: </style></head><body></body></html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wait for some element in `htmlContent` after page is loaded.

```js
  await page.goto(`data:text/html;charset=UTF-8,${htmlContent}`, {
    waitUntil: "networkidle0",
  });
  await page.waitForSelector('#visible-element')
```

Comment: Hi thanks for you help, i replaced await page.goto(`data:text/html;charset=UTF-8,${htmlContent}`, {
    waitUntil: "networkidle0",
  }); with await page.setContent(htmlContent); and it works fine for me.

Comment: @Jslover I am glad this works. It would be good to accept the answer as correct one, so any other who has the same question could see how to solve it.